# Macro requires three arguments but only two given

Tags: macros

The below function takes three arguments:
void FUN(int a, int b, int c)
There are situations where the first argument is not required . For optimization, a macro(with the same name as that of the function name) is defined in such a way that :

**#define FUN(a, b, c)  FUN(b,c)**

**#define MACRO1**  //macro has no value- trying to indicate that argument 1 is not necessary in the function call.

The following statement gives the error :Macro requires 3 arguments, but only 2 given
**FUN(MACRO1 x,y)**
I am using the gcc compiler for compilation. I used the "-E" option to see the pre-processed output and it looks like the outer macro is resolved first (FUN) and then the inner macro (MACRO1) and hence resulting in this error. 
Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

When the first argument is not required, give it a default value (say `0`). Then use `#define FUN2(b, c) FUN(0,b,c)`. You cannot have a different macro with the same name as the function, so I named it `FUN2`.

P.S. In C++11 (and maybe earlier), you can directly assign default values in function definitions and declarations. Note, however, that you would need to move the first parameter to the end.